# ATI Radeon 6630M and xorg

Tags: 12.04, xorg, ati

The problem is whenever I update xorg, it breaks my whole system. I get a black screen at the login screen.

I own a Dell Inspiron N4110 with a ATI Radeon 6630M graphics card. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed fglrx because my laptop tends to overheat. Everything works now except when I update xorg.

Is there a fix for this or do I just ignore the xorg updates? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Sony Vaio VPCCA with that graphics card. I followed [this Spanish language tutorial](http://www.vagos.es/showthread.php?t=1784193) and it works.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This is especially so since the tutorial itself is in Spanish rather than English.